# Using SolrNet 4.0 alpha 1 or later with Autofac

Tags: autofac, solrnet

I notice the latest alpha of [SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) supports [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) integration.

This [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MultiCoreAccess) discusses how to integrate with the existing containers (StructureMap, Windsor, etc) but I couldn't find any examples on how to integrate with Autofac.

Since we're using Autofac 2.5.2, I've put in an assembly redirect from the old version that SolrNet wants:

```
<runtime>
    <!-- SolrNet wants to use an old version of Autofac -->
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.2.4.900" newVersion="2.5.2.830"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Which works ok. Now onto the actual registration, I've tried this:

```
builder.Register(c => new AutofacContrib.SolrNet.SolrNetModule("http://localhost:8983/solr/"));
```

Where `builder` is my Autofac `ContainerBuilder`.

But I can't figure out how to let SolrNet know I want results mapped to `Dictionary<string, Object>`.

Any examples of Autofac integration with SolrNet? As code is preferrable, although it would be good to see the XML config version, as well.

PS. I did notice the latest changes.txt on the SolrNet wiki mention an upgrade to Autofac 2.5 so my assembly binding can hopefully go away soon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This wiki page discusses how to integrate with the existing containers (StructureMap, Windsor, etc) but I couldn't find any examples on how to integrate with Autofac.

It's normal for alpha releases to be poorly documented. Please consider sending a patch for the docs if you're using this feature.

> Since we're using Autofac 2.5.2, I've put in an assembly redirect from the old version that SolrNet wants:

This has been upgraded to 2.5.2.830 in master branch, you might want to use that. You can get binaries from the [build server](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project36&guest=1).

> But I can't figure out how to let SolrNet know I want results mapped to `Dictionary<string, Object>`.

This isn't implemented yet for the Autofac module. Please consider [forking the repository](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet) and implementing it. However, using `Dictionary<string, Object>` as document type should be a last resort only. Whenever possible you should prefer to [map fields to properly typed properties in a class](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping).

> Any examples of Autofac integration with SolrNet? As code is preferrable, although it would be good to see the XML config version, as well.

See the [tests](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/master/AutofacContrib.SolrNet.Tests).

> PS. I did notice the latest changes.txt on the SolrNet wiki mention an upgrade to Autofac 2.5 so my assembly binding can hopefully go away soon.

Again, I recommend using a recent built from the master branch.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We have to use `Dictionary<string, object>` as our schema is all dynamic fields and is changeable on the fly at runtime. I managed to get Autofac to register and give me an instance of a class implementing ISolrOpertions but as the mapper doesn't yet support dictionaries I probably have to stick to the existing ServiceLocator container.

Comment: @Spud : "our schema is all dynamic fields and is changeable on the fly at runtime" -> doesn't sound like a good idea...

Comment: Perhaps not, but it is what it is. We're trying to have multiple schemas (read: hundreds) defined externally and documents uploaded to Solr that adhere to these schemas - and thus I don't want to create classes to represent them all, given they can be changed by the business at will. Apart from the obvious loss of strong typing by using a Dictionary, do you see any other pitfalls in regards to using Solr with this approach?

Comment: @Spud : "The more heterogeneous data you have in one field or in one index, the less useful it is." ( http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign ).